# Shutdown a program which constanly changes window name with AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I've recently started creating some simple scripts with autoHotKey, and I'd like to know if it is possible to close Spotify, which changes window title for every song.
I've tried with
`Process, Close, Spotify`
but it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Is the name "Spotify" in the window title at all? And do you have access to the Window Spy utility that is used in conjunction with AHK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet works for me:

```
while(Winexist("ahk_exe Spotify.exe"))
    WinClose
```

Spotify is weird in that it appears to create many processes of itself when launched,
[image]

and that when you run a command like `WinClose, ahk_exe Spotify.exe` once, it does not immediately close the program (you can still use and interact with the GUI, but if you attempt to move the window by dragging the top bar, Spotify crashes).

However, if you spam that command over and over again, Spotify eventually closes as intended. So, in order to deal with this, let's create a program such that while there still remain Spotify processes, close Spotify Processes. Then, once there are no Spotify processes remaining, stop trying to close Spotify.

Comment: It's probably more elegant to count the number of Spotify.exe processes running, then loop through each of them, ending them. There's also probably a way to check which process is the parent process (I don't remember how at the moment), and ending that will end any other currently-running processes too.